# Where to download AUnit 3 (for Ada)?

Tags: ada, gnat, aunit

Where to download the AUnit (AFAIK, the latest version is 3) for Ada (particularly for GNAT-4.9)?

I don't care whether this AUnit is licensed GPL or otherwise, because it is used only for my test program and the license of the test program does not matter.

I have a Debian system with `gnat-4.9`. The package `libaunit2-dev` does not install with this version of GNAT. And it seems that `libaunit2-dev` is AUnit 1 rather than AUnit 3. I would prefer the latest version.

Answer (score 3):

Go to http://libre.adacore.com and select *Download*, *Free Software*, *Build your download package*, (any operating system)/*GNAT GPL 2014*, *GNAT Ada GPL 2014*, *Sources*, click on `aunit-gpl-2014-src.tar.gz` (not the checkbox, since you only want the one archive).

I’d recommend **not** running plain `make install` to install with the compiler, because AdaCore packages assume a different file structure from that used by Debian; in particular, `gnatmake` will *not* find `aunit.gpr`. Also, you may confuse `apt-get`. Install in `~/local` instead by

```
make install INSTALL=$HOME/local
```

(yes, I know, it should be `prefix` not `INSTALL` but AdaCore aren’t all that consistent about this)

and then include `$HOME/local/lib/gnat` in your `$ADA_PROJECT_PATH`.